# What music streaming services work on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, streaming, spotify

I tried downloading Spotify via terminal and thru Clementine and couldn't get it working.  I like sites like Spotify and Rhapsody because one can listen/stream full albums on demand.  What are the recommended music streamers on Ubuntu?

Comment: Spotify works perfectly on ubuntu. What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Answer (score 7):

There is a [Spotify package](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/) for Ubuntu that works well, and [pithos](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-pandora-radio-client-ubuntu/) works with Pandora.

Comment: Beware that you need to install `libgcrypt11` manually, since it's not included in the Ubuntu 15 repos.

Answer (score 5):

If you are ok with using web apps, then there are quite a few:

- Google Play Music - https://play.google.com/music
- Spotify - https://open.spotify.com/browse
- Songza - http://songza.com
- Amazon Music - https://music.amazon.com/
- iHeartRadio - http://www.iheart.com/
- Pandora - http://www.pandora.com
- Soundcloud - https://soundcloud.com/stream

Comment: If you use the chrome or chromium browser, you can even install Google Play Music as a pop out app accessible from the dash

Comment: Along with this, there is an awesome chrome app called Streamkeys to intercept media keys and send to a chrome tab (works with virtually everything). https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen

Answer (score 2):

Here are additional ones not mentioned

- [Nuvola Player](https://tiliado.eu/nuvolaplayer/)
- [Amarok](https://amarok.kde.org/)
- [Tomahawk](https://www.tomahawk-player.org/)

Comment: desting deezer in nuvola 3, it  just installs and opens a webkit browser page (that is a browser), so that deezer is played just as if it were in Firefox and Chrome, which makes  the use of a separate 'player' useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [VkAudioSaver](http://vkaudiosaver.ru/en/about.html). It is available in Ubuntu Software Center. You can stream music online and download music for offline playing for free.